# Having a dynamically animated JFrame using JLayeredFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I am trying to get the basic functionality of animation to work. I had gotten it to work before in an RPG project, but now it is a little different because I am using several JComponents, organized by JPanel's and a JLayeredPane. My issue is making the "redrawing" work. I have a for-loop as seen in the bottom of the code where I try to slightly change the LegsComponent then add that to the JPane->JLayeredPane-> then JFrame. But for some reason the LegsComponent does not appear. Do you have any advice? Thank you!

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Main
{
    public static void go()
    {
    JFrame fr = new JFrame();
    JLayeredPane lpane = new JLayeredPane();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();

    int size = 120;

    p.setSize(500, 500);
    p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    p2.setSize(500, 500);
    p2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    p2.setOpaque(false);

    p3.setSize(500, 500);
    p3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p3, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    p3.setOpaque(false);

    final int frHEIGHT = 500;
    final int frWIDTH = 500;

    fr.setSize(frWIDTH, frHEIGHT);

    BodyComponent bC = new BodyComponent(frWIDTH, frHEIGHT, size);
    BackgroundComponent bkC = new BackgroundComponent(frWIDTH, frHEIGHT, size);

    //initializing LegComponent params
    double x = frWIDTH/3;
    double y = frHEIGHT/2;
    double setX = x+size/2;
    double setY = y+size/2;

    LegsComponent lC = new LegsComponent(x, y, size, setX, setY);

    p.add(bkC);
    p2.add(bC);
    p3.add(lC);

    lpane.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);

    lpane.add(p, new Integer(0));
    lpane.add(p2, new Integer(2));
    lpane.add(p3, new Integer(1));

    fr.getContentPane().add(lpane);
    fr.setVisible(true);

    for (int i = 45; i > 0; i--){
        JPanel P3 = new JPanel();
        JLayeredPane lPane = new JLayeredPane();
        double n = .01111*i;

        lPane.removeAll();

        LegsComponent lC2 = new LegsComponent(x+n, y+n, size, setX, setY);

        fr.getContentPane().removeAll();

        P3.add(lC2);
        P3.setOpaque(false);

        lPane.add(p, new Integer(0));
        lPane.add(p2, new Integer(2));
        lPane.add(P3, new Integer(1));

        fr.getContentPane().add(lPane);

        fr.setVisible(true);

        Tools.pause(100);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The short answer is why are you using components?  Why aren't you using custom painting?  Next, you're fighting the layout manager, which is never going to end well. Next, you're running the risk of blocking the event dispatching thread, which will prevent the UI from been updated. Generally, your idea is ill conceived

Comment: Also, I don't see the point of `lPane.removeAll();`, when you've just created a new instance of it and are just going to add it to the frame....

Comment: Oh, and if you're not running your code within the context of the EDT, then you're violating the single thread nature of the API, which could generate all sorts of nasty painting artifcates

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses